# Cookie for subdomain

Tags: php, cookies, subdomain

I´m building a big project with many services, like Game Hosting, "YouTube" alternative, and many other stuff.
Every service has subdomain, like kwindu.eu for GameHosting, play.kwindu.eu for "YouTube" alternative, pack.kwindu.eu,....

If you want to log in, you are forwarded to kwindu.eu, then you log in and php script generate cookie for ".kwindu.eu"

Here is the cookie code, I´m using:

```
setcookie("logedin", $session, time() + 86400, "/", ".kwindu.eu");
```

This works good with chrome, if i check cookies there is a cookie for kwindu.eu and everything works fine.
But when i try to login with Firefox or IE, system show me as loged in only at kwindu.eu.

Comment: This is wierd. I'm using Firefox and tried your method, and it works for me. Are you sure there isnt any other issue?

Comment: Yea it was in php code that should check e-mail. It messed it up, it is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the dot.  That is:

```
setcookie("logedin", $session, time() + 86400, "/", "kwindu.eu");
```

The dot was required for older browsers implementing [this RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2109.html).

See if that works.

Comment: What do you see in Firebug? Is the cookie set correctly? This will help troubleshoot further

Comment: But web like ignoring it. Web showing login button.

Comment: If i try to echo it by php it is showing cookie fine.

Comment: And php is succesfully connected to DB.

Comment: It looks there is problem with changing session in DB. It is using old one.

Comment: Your screenshot still shows a dot before the domain. Did you clear that cookie before testing without the dot?

Comment: It is putting there that dot automaticly. I deleted cookies edited php ini so there is no settings about cookies at all, and checked code.